# Excel 2010, Insert/Create Word Object, Display Page 2 Only

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

At my work, Excel is king. We make lots of notes across worksheets for any given workbook. We have a proprietary on page note addin, but it primarily runs off text box. But we can't do stuff with text box such as spell check. These notes get reviewed by supervisor by the way.

I created a word document that contains all the notes I need. Each page in this doc is for a specidic worksheet. I would like to insert a specific page into the worksheet as an  object.

The problem is, whether I create from file or insert new object, it always displays the first page.  Let's day I want to display page 3 of my doc into any worksheet of my excel file. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your use case. If you want to have a link to open to the correct spot in the word document from excel.

inside of word, make a bookmark for where you want to open. Say Spot for the spot you want it to open with.

Inside of excel, insert a hyperlink, you the browse to find your file

at the bottom for link add #spot which indicates where in the document you want it to open.

if instead you want to include a copy your page 3 data inside of excel without using a link -
Copy the page you want
Go to excel where you want the data to reside
use paste special, (Home ribbon)
will get a menu that includes microsoft word, picture, text and other choices
use the one you want.

Comment: Thank you bvaughn. I never saw the option to paste special as an word object before. I thought any object was through Insert ribbon. Thanks again.